# How do you print the highest and smallest number of ASCII value in string java

Tags: java, ascii

I found it, thank u mate. I actually too confuse yesterday, till i forget everything that i learnt. So here is my code, what do you think?

I just don't know why my minChar not working when i delete this code :

```
if(stringValue.charAt(i) != 32){
```

```
    public class MyString {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            String stringValue = "Hello World";
            SearchMyString str = new SearchMyString(stringValue);
            str.stringInfo();
            
        }  
    }
    
    class SearchMyString{
        
        private char maxChar;
        private char minChar;
        String stringValue;
        int ascii;
        
        public SearchMyString(String stringValue){
            this.stringValue = stringValue;
        }
        
        char getMinChar(String stringValue, int n){
            minChar = 'z';
    
            for(int i = 0;i<n-1;i++){
                if(stringValue.charAt(i)<minChar){
                    if(stringValue.charAt(i) != 32){
                    minChar = stringValue.charAt(i);
                    ascii = (int)stringValue.charAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            return minChar;
        }
            
        public void stringInfo(){
            
            int size = stringValue.length();

            System.out.println("Smallest char : "+getMinChar(stringValue,size) + "\tASCII : " + ascii);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: You create the class and its members and methods, but you are nto calling them anywhere.

Comment: Yups, i have no idea bout that, i confuse bout it.

Comment: then learn it. Its simple to jst google how to call a method of a class

Comment: Two thoughts related to your problem but not the answer: 1. getMinChar and getMaxChar should both be static methods, as they don't depend of the state of the object 2. You should comment your methods like "max character by ASCII value case sensitive ascii/latin characters A to z only"

Comment: Ok, i actually forget the static methods. After my script run i'll give the methods comment.

Comment: Glad to help :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
public static char getMaxChar(String a){
       char max = a.charAt(0); 
        for (int i=0; i<a.length(); i++){
            if ((a.charAt(i) > max)){ 
                max = a.charAt(i);  
            }
        }
        return max; 
    }
```

Test case:

```
ACBDEFG
```

Returns

```
G
```

**So what did we change?**

For starters, if we are trying to get the character in the String that has the highest `char` int value, we don't need `n`. We are looping through the String, so all we need is the length, which can already be supplied by the `.length()` method.

To call the method, just do:

```
SearchMyString search = new SearchMyString();
search.getMaxChar(nama);
```

**EDIT:** So to make the method more reliable, instead of automatically setting `max` to `'A'`, we can set it to the first char of `a` (e.g, `a.charAt(0)`)

Comment: Thanks, le me try it.

Comment: @Zakhel If my answer solves the question, please consider accepting!

Comment: I got it when i write it in my Main, but when i write it on Void the output was nothing.

Comment: @Zakhel Please describe more clearly what you mean by "void"

Comment: String nama = "abcdefg";
        int namaLength = nama.length();
        char max = 'A';
       
        for (int i=0; i<namaLength; i++)     
            if (nama.charAt(i) > max) 
                max = nama.charAt(i); 
        System.out.print(max);

Output : G

but when i make the method, i got nothing.

Comment: @Zakhel You need to print out `max`

Comment: You can start loop from `1` means `int i=1`

Comment: Thank u mate, i have no idea yesterday.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Zakhel If my answer answers your question, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!